# Stopping prometheus docker container gracefully

Tags: docker, centos, prometheus

I am running prometheus inside a docker container on centos. I wanted to know if there is a way to stop prometheus gracefully (without data corruption). Will running `docker stop` work? I could not find any docs on this and I am new to linux, docker and prometheus.

Comment: Which image do you use? https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/Dockerfile seems to be the official image.

Comment: yes i am using the official image, just want to gracefully stop prometheus, patch/reboot the server, start prometheus again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work.

`docker stop` sends a SIGTERM signal to the process at PID1, which is prometheus if you're using the official image. If no answer is received in a period of time (default 10s), docker will then send the SIGKILL signal and kill the process.

Prometheus is expected to shut down cleanly when receiving a SIGTERM however this may take longer than 10s. See
https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#troubleshooting

You might have to extend the time docker waits before sending a SIGKILL.
e.g.: `docker stop --time 50`
You'll have to find the correct setting here depending on your Prometheus setup.